# Git - No source directories were detected at 'path'. Please check URL and try again

Tags: git, github, import, enterprise

I am trying to use the "Git Importer" tool (https://help.github.com/articles/importing-source-code-to-github/) to copy a private repo from a GitHub Enterprise server to my personal account at Github.com (which also has a private repo) and when I run the tool I first get a pop-up like this:
[image]

I enter the credential that I use to login to the Enterprise server, it passes the authentication and after a while of loading I get this error:
[image]

Any idea why this is happening? I have tried using the clone url (with .git at the end of the url) but the exact same thing happens.

EDIT: I also tried importing the repo to BitBucket and BitBucket says that "no repo exists at that URL". What the hell? I am staring at the repo right now! It 100% exists.

Comment: I guess you could always clone locally, then push the master branch (and other useful branches) to an upstream of your choice.

Comment: @EqualityInTech I have tried to clone the repo, change the remote url to match my new GitHub repo and then tried to push. But it didn't work. It gave me an error (but I can't remember right now what the error said).

Comment: @EqualityInTech Now I remember. The error I got when I pushed said "Cannot push these commits as they contain an email address marked as private on GitHub.". I can't push it because one of my team members is using a private email for his commits? Is that it?

Comment: @EqualityInTech Hmm, I solved the problem. I simply unchecked the tickbox in my Account settings -> Email that said "Block command line pushes that expose my email". I don't know how or why... but it works now I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never managed to solve this specific issue but I found a work-around by cloning my Enterprise repo to a local one, changing the remote repo URL to the URL of my new GitHub repo and then pushing it.

First time I pushed I got an error that said "Cannot push these commits as they contain an email address marked as private on GitHub.". I fixed this by going into my account on GitHub.com and then Settings -> Email -> "Block command line pushes that expose my email" -> Untick